# How to get access token using oauth 2.0 authorization grant type in rest assured

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, postman, rest-assured

I have an api with oauth2.0 authorization grant type authentication which has the following steps -

1. Get method for authorization code which opens up a form in browser where you need to enter credentials. This results in a series of post redirect requests and finally returns a **authorization code** in third post response header
2. Now a post request is sent, with grant type authorization code containing client credentials and the above authorization code we got from the get request, in the body and it returns the **access token**

This is how it works in postman. How can I achieve the same thing using **Rest Assured**?

Comment: A work-around I did in the pass is that: 1. Using selenium (headless) to login. 2 Extract access_token from cookie, then save to global var or file. 3 Get the access_token then do the API call. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need two handlers

Handler 1:

- To redirect to oauth server. (requeter should identity list of grant types, generate url with client_id and state and redirect application to this url)
- Once end user signs in and allows the grant. (assumed that user allows)

Handler 2:

- oauth server redirects back to postman with a authorization_code and state.
- You need to configure redirect to your server callback url.
- Once you receive these two
- Verify state is same as what you sent. if yes proceed.
- send authorization_code, cleint_secret, client_id back to server to recieve access_token and refresh_token
- Use access_token to access data.
- Use refresh_token to get new access_token.